# HTML5 Speech Synthesis

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech

Simply put, it is very simple and contains minimum amount of conding (only two lines)

but I am still not hearing anything.   But Google TTS works perfectly on my laptop.

I only see "one two" alert when I run the page below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> </head>

<body>

<script>
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello baby');
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
    alert("one two");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And I use Google Chrome Ver 36.  How do I view the errors in my JavaScript?   Thanks a lot Stack Overflow!

Comment: just realised out code is the same. Your code works for me in Chrome 36.

Comment: Do you hear the word "hello"?

Comment: I hear the whole thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I helped put speech synth in google chrome. Glad you are using it!

**Edit: I ran your code in the Chrome 36 console and it works fine **

You should be using it like so:

```
if('speechSynthesis' in window){
    var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('hello baby');
    speech.lang = 'en-US';
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}
```

You can check errors in the console in chrome by right clicking on the page and in the contextual menu, clicking the last option ( inspect element ).

More here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I am currently building a mobile application that can help students in non-English speaking countries, such as South Korea, Germany, Japan, China, France, learn English.

Do you recommend Google TTS or HTML5 TTS?   And if I choose to go with Google TTS, do I have to give credits to Google somewhere in my application?  If that is required then I do not have any problem with giving Google credit.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works nicely, but if you want to pick another voice use this:

```
function saySomething(whatToSay){
  const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
  // enter your voice here, because voices list loads asynchronously.. check the console.log below.
  getVoice("Google US English", synth)  
    .then(voice => {
      var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(whatToSay);
      utterThis.voice = voice;
      synth.speak(utterThis);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("error: ", error));
}

function getVoice(voiceName, synth){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    synth.onvoiceschanged = function(){
      const voices = synth.getVoices();

      console.log("see all available languages and voices on your system: ", voices);

      for(let i = 0; i < voices.length ; i++) {
          if(voices[i].name == voiceName) {
            resolve(voices[i]);
          }
        }
    }
    synth.getVoices();
  });
}

saySomething("Mu ha ha! Works now.");
```